Is the Lie- derivative $L_{X+Y}\omega=L_{X}\omega+L_{Y}\omega$?
I would like to know if $L_{X+Y}\omega=L_{X}\omega+L_{Y}\omega$, because I am interested in the following

I would like to know I f I can write $L_{\partial_{t}}\gamma+L_{X}\gamma$
Unfortunately I can not find anything on the Internet.
Many thanks in advance.

Sort of…but I am wondering why it is not covered in Lee‘s book.

@Hans One can get it as a consequence of the Cartan magic formula, i.e. $L_X=[i_x,\mathrm{d}]$, which is presented in Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds (2nd Edition) as Theorem 14.35

@agt okay I See, thanks. is it possible to derive it from the definition as well? I am wondering why it is not mentioned in the book. Is there a book that mentions it? In Tu's book I couldn't find anything either.

It's not obvious from the definition, because there's no obvious formula for the flow of the sum of two non-commuting vector fields.

@TedShifrin Is there a book that shows this?

Shows what? What I said is just a fact about ODEs. Even in one dimension, if you know how to solve $\dot x(t) = f(x(t))$ and $\dot x(t)=g(x(t))$, do you know how to solve $\dot x(t) = (f+g)(x(t))$?

Shows $L_{X+Y}\omega=L_{X}\omega+L_{Y}\omega$

No book that I know does this, but it’s an easy exercise to give a local coordinates formula for $L_X\omega$ (which is most likely in some books), and then it becomes obvious.

In particular, using the definition, you can show that $L_X dx^i = \sum\frac{\partial a^i}{\partial x^j}dx^j$ when $X=\sum a^j\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}$.
